# Script error. calling sleep

Tags: dart

Using https://dartpad.dartlang.org

The following gives `Script error.` in the CONSOLE?

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  sleep(const Duration(seconds:1));
}
```

Comment: Dartpad can't use `dart:io` because it compiles to JavaScript whete only `dart:html` is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_dart_online.php
- https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-dart-online

Couldn't reproduce the issue, dartpad throws an error though, yes.

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
    sleep(const Duration(seconds:1));
    print('This will be logged to the console in the browser.');
}
```

Results in:

```
$dart main.dart
This will be logged to the console in the browser.
```

Error on DartPad looks like a bug with sleep:

```
wrapException
_ProcessUtils__sleep
main
<anonymous>
<anonymous>
<anonymous>
<anonymous>
replaceJavaScript
messageHandler/<
```

However using sleep this way won't break DartPad.

```
import 'dart:async';

Future sleep1() {
  return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => "1");
}

main() {
    sleep1();
    print('This will be logged to the console in the browser.');
}
```